# Altering command to start application by mouse click - how to

Tags: command-line, bash, mouse, bashrc, alias

I have [Google Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Earth) installed on my [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) and, in order to display clamped polygons on it, I have to start it with the command `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 googleearth`.

I would like to know if I can make the command `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 googleearth` the default way to launch Google Earth when I click a [KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) file. Right now I have tried to set `alias googleearth='LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 googleearth'`, but this didn't work. I couldn't find anything online (the terms are too broad), and I didn't find any documentation about this.

BTW, I know I can probably just set the `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE` variable beforehand in `.bashrc`, but I would like to know this because of plans for other programs as well (such as run with options and things like that).

Answer (score 1):

The alias you have tried `alias googleearth='LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 googleearth'` should work, maybe you did this:

```
alias googleearth='LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 googleearth' ; googleearth
```

or you used the alias in a script or in a fuction. Nothing of this works.

If it still doesn't work for you, try creating a function instead of an alias. Don't forget to provide an absolute pathname to the `googleearth` command inside the function so it's not interpreted as recursive function.